# Scala PLAY same routes

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I have same routes in routes file but their action is different as shown

```
GET         /counts                                 controllers.Application.getAllCountsByFeature(features)
GET         /counts                                 controllers.Application.getAllCounts()
```

I'm calling both routes as

```
http://localhost:9000/segments/counts?features=feature_1,feature_2-feature_3
http://localhost:9000/segments/counts
```

But it's not working. I want play to recognize which route is called based on query string. If query string is provided then it should hit getAllCountsByFeature method and so on.

Is there any way?
I'm using Play 2.5.9

Comment: Just use one route, Do different query inside one action

Comment: I would recommend to use 2 routes, or 1 route and do the logic inside the controller with optional query params as others stated before

Answer (score 2):

Use one route with optional parameter

```
GET         /counts                                 controllers.Application.getAllCountsByFeature(features: Option[String])
```

and then

```
def getAllCountsByFeature(features: Option[String]) = Action {
  features match{
    case Some(f) => //..
    case None => getAllCounts()
  }
}
```